# Subquery returned more than 1 value showing error in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= 
or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I am getting this error when I execute the `select` query and `insert` that data in tmptable by using `into` keyword.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT 
       distinct Register.appRegName as RegName, 
       (select appSubMarks 
        from tblsubjectmaster 
        where appSubID = 1) as SubjectMarks , 
       chapter.appChapter, 
       (select count(appTestCurrectAns) 
        from tbltest 
        group by appTestChapterID) as AttempQuestion,  
       chapter.appChapter, 
       subject.appSubName, 
       (select sum(appTestMarks) 
        from tbltest 
        where test.appTestUserID = 1) as CorrectAns 

 into TmpResultPrint 
 from tblTest test 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblRegistration register 
 ON test.appTestUserID = register.appRegID 

 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblchaptermaster chapter 
 ON chapter.appchapid = test.apptestchapterid 

 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSubjectMaster subject 
 ON subject.appSubID = test.appTestSubjectID 
 where test.appTestUserID = 1
```

And I know that why it is getting error. Because I use the group by in sub query. If I remove it then it works properly. But I dont want to remove because I want to count the data by their individual chapter ID.

How can I solve this...???

Comment: `SELECT count(appTestCurrectAns)
                 FROM   tbltest
                 GROUP  BY appTestChapterID` will return multiple rows potentially. What are you trying to do there? Give example data and desired results.

Comment: I want to count multiple data which is their same apptestchapterid.... Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Give example data and desired results.

Comment: Use of distinct is usually an indication that your query is not logically correct. In addition, you make no attempt to correlate your subqueries with the rows in the outer/main query - so the values generate have no relationship to the row where user id = 1. If you want help, you need to explain what you are doing and what your schema is actually modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it one of two ways:

Way #1:

Change the subquery to get to filter for that row (which I think is what you were trying to do):

```
(select count(appTestCurrectAns) from tbltest t1 where t1.appTestChapterID = test.appTestChapterID)  as  AttempQuestion
```

Way #2:
Join to the subquery, something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT distinct Register.appRegName as RegName, 
(select appSubMarks from tblsubjectmaster where appSubID = 1) as SubjectMarks , chapter.appChapter, 
SUBQ.AttempQuestion  
,chapter.appChapter, 
subject.appSubName, (select sum(appTestMarks) from tbltest where test.appTestUserID = 1) as CorrectAns  
into TmpResultPrint 
from tblTest test LEFT OUTER JOIN tblRegistration register ON test.appTestUserID = register.appRegID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblchaptermaster chapter ON chapter.appchapid = test.apptestchapterid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSubjectMaster subject ON subject.appSubID = test.appTestSubjectID 
INNER JOIN (select appTestChapterID, count(appTestCurrectAns) AttempQuestion from tbltest group by appTestChapterID) SUBQ on SUBQ.appTesterUserID = test.appTestUserID
where test.appTestUserID = 1
```